# OpenCV scale 3d cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a 3d cv::Mat that I want to resize by some ratio. 
Mat size is 130 x 512 x 512 and I want to resize it by 3 x 0.9 x 0.9 but I don't know how.

I want to do this because I extract slices from that volume and I do not want to resize the slice every time.

I use `cv::resize(sliceAxial, out, cv::Size(), 0.9, 3, cv::INTER_CUBIC);` to resize the slice but I would like to do something like `cv::resize(img3d, out, cv::Size(), 3, 0.9, 0.9, cv::INTER_CUBIC);` to resize the volume.

I searched over the internet but I could not find anything like this. If you can help I would appreciate it.

Thank you!

Comment: Isotropic huh? I mean I know how to do it, but not without [itk] tag on the question...

Comment: I use OpenCV in my project and I do not want to add another library. Can it be done in OpenCV?

Comment: I don' think so unless you write it from scratch. But if you compiled OpenCV `WITH_VTK`, there should be another one.